# What can cause the body of a shopify webhook to not contain a 'customer' array?

Tags: shopify

We subscribe to the shopify 'order fulfilled' webhook. For the past month we've had no problem at all parsing the data which is posted to us and taking action based on it. In particular, every request has contained a 'customer' array, consisting of (at least) 'email', 'first_name' and 'last_name'.

We have just received data without a 'customer' array. On superficial inspection, the order appears no different to any other order we've processed, so there's no obvious reason why this would be the case.

The data we've received does contain an email, first_name, and last_name, but not in a 'customer' array. We could modify our code to look in other places to extract this data, but we'd rather not without understanding why we were making the change.

Has there been an announced change to the structure of the data Shopify posts that we've somehow missed?

What are the conditions which would cause the 'customer' array to not appear in the posted data? Is there any location in the posted data which is *guaranteed* to always contain email, first_name and last_name so we can prevent this happening again?

Comment: I believe the customer data is normally in a hash when the response is for an order resource.

It sounds like it could be a race condition in Shopify.  Did you take note of the order_id?  If you fetch the order through the API now will it show the customer hash now?

Comment: Hi! I've just tested this by requesting the order by id using ShopifyAPI::Order.find, and the returned order still doesn't have the customer data hash. If it helps I can send the order id and a YAML dump of the data we do receive to someone at Shopify?

Comment: You can email it to me directly, john.duff@shopify.com

Comment: This has been a feature of Order WebHooks since the API was released. You have to wrap an idiot check around customer hash due to this.

Comment: Hmm - one response saying it's 'normally' there, one saying it might not be there... I'm happy to idiot-check it if that's what we need to do, but best would be some insight into why it sometimes happens! Don't really want to introduce conditional branches into our code without understanding why we're doing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webhook handlers should handle the case were the customer information on an order is missing.  This can happen in the legitimate case were a customer is deleted, which might be done manually by the merchant.

In your case specifically, the problem was that the customer was not getting associated with an order.  This was a bug in a library Shopify uses for background job processing, which was not retrying jobs that got killed by the kernel for running out of memory.  In this case the job would create a customer for an order for new customers. I have fixed the relevant bugs that should prevent background jobs from being lost in this situation.

Comment: Great - thanks for the fixes. Also good to know why we should be handling the 'customer data missing' case - we're very happy to program defensively, but prefer to know why we're doing so, rather than just putting in some 'cargo cult' fallbacks. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Similarly I should add that variant_id on line_items in the order can also be `null` if the product variant is deleted.